# What is the maximum ilvl you can find on vendors/merchants/blacksmith from town or via quest/event?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the max ilvl for each vendor/merchant?
Do act 1/2/3/4 merchants have different ilvl 'drops'?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/vendor-ilevel-over-inferno

Comment: If you are asking about vendor iLvls in ***all** difficulties not just Inferno, please mention that (in which case, maybe original question could be improved). Also 'via quest' is an interesting point (often vendors offer rare when encountered outside town), but its not particularly useful.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a ilvl 60 or higher on a merchant, even the quest merchants.